# record time when an object appears in window

Tags: opencv, go, tracker

I am using gocv and I have a window with a video playing. I have taken an ROI of that window where I know that there is movement. I have dilated and converted the colour to HSV. I can now find the largest contour, within my ROI and draw a box around it.

However I would like to take a timestamp every time an object is detected to move within the window. Thats not so hard, however I only want to take 1 time, not lots and lots, which is what currently happens.

My code currently looks like

```
for {
        gocv.GaussianBlur(imgCrop, &imgCrop, blur, 0, 0, gocv.BorderReflect101)
        gocv.CvtColor(imgCrop, &imgCrop, gocv.ColorBGRToHSV)
        thresholded := gocv.NewMat()
        gocv.InRangeWithScalar(imgCrop,
            lhsv,
            hhsv,
            &thresholded)
        gocv.Erode(thresholded, &thresholded, kernel)
        gocv.Dilate(thresholded, &thresholded, kernel)
        const minArea = 500
        cnt, set := bestContour(thresholded, minArea)
        gocv.Line(&imgCrop, image.Pt(0, line), image.Pt(imgCrop.Cols(), line), color.RGBA{255, 0, 0, 0}, 2)
        if set {
            cntBox := gocv.BoundingRect(cnt)
            gocv.Rectangle(&imgCrop, cntBox, blue, 2)
            log.Println("time ", time.Since(startTime))
        }
        // draw it.
        gocv.Rectangle(&img, rect, blue, 3)
        wi.IMShow(img)
        wc.IMShow(imgCrop)
        wt.IMShow(thresholded)
        if wi.WaitKey(1) == 27 || wt.WaitKey(1) == 27 {
            break
        }
}
```

and that outputs

[image]

However this could spit a time out multiple times as it detects the same movement multiple times before the object leaves the ROI. I am trying to get just one timing for each time an object enters the ROI

I added the red line as i thought there might be a trick where I can check if the cntBox is crossing the line or has gone over it, and then take a reading, however my brain fused.

I also thought perhaps I could draw a rectangle within the ROI and check if the blue cntbox enters the rectangle, but same issue....

I noticed there is an example of using moments to do this, which I tried, however I believe the moments are doing the simple detection as well. I wonder whether moments can be used with my existing code.

FYI there will only ever be one object in the ROI.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you shared a function and I was only able to copy part of the code so my syntax be off. so I will elaborate a little more...

I think you are grabbing many frames per second and objects won't enter and leave your ROI in the span of a single frame so you'd like to filter out any consecutive frames with "hits" in your ROI?

I added a variable "timestampbuffer" which just a counter that will tick down every time a "hit" occurs in your ROI, once it counts down completely (30 frames, which would be a second if you're (hopefully) clocking frames that fast) will reset and you now only send a timestamp at best once a second.

Keep in mind I haven't been programming long, but I have done this with some YOLO videocapture work so although it may sound primitve; it does work.

```
#add a "buffer" for your calls to grab a timestamp. the buffer delays the calls to write a timestamp
timeStampBuffer=30
        gocv.GaussianBlur(imgCrop, &imgCrop, blur, 0, 0, gocv.BorderReflect101)
        gocv.CvtColor(imgCrop, &imgCrop, gocv.ColorBGRToHSV)
        thresholded := gocv.NewMat()
        gocv.InRangeWithScalar(imgCrop,
            lhsv,
            hhsv,
            &thresholded)
        gocv.Erode(thresholded, &thresholded, kernel)
        gocv.Dilate(thresholded, &thresholded, kernel)
        const minArea = 500
        cnt, set := bestContour(thresholded, minArea)
        gocv.Line(&imgCrop, image.Pt(0, line), image.Pt(imgCrop.Cols(), line), color.RGBA{255, 0, 0, 0}, 2)
        if set {
            cntBox := gocv.BoundingRect(cnt)
            gocv.Rectangle(&imgCrop, cntBox, blue, 2)
            if timeStampBuffer=30:
                log.Println("time ", time.Since(startTime))
            else if timeStampBuffer=0:
                timeStampBuffer=31
            timeStampBuffer-=1
        }
        // draw it.
        gocv.Rectangle(&img, rect, blue, 3)
        wi.IMShow(img)
        wc.IMShow(imgCrop)
        wt.IMShow(thresholded)
        if wi.WaitKey(1) == 27 || wt.WaitKey(1) == 27 {
            break
        }
```

Comment: hey thanks for responding, I edited orig question to show the loop that occurs per frame. As a result I have modified your answer in my code and it does indeed work, however I have to adjust the number of frames to wait.
I do wonder if there is a more robust way to do this - this relies on two motions not occuring within the allocated number of frames. I hoped that a tracking mechanism might work?